# trying to sync up my typings implementation

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

The tfs repo at my company was migrated while I was in the middle of an Angular2 implementation.  So now I'm migrating my Angular2 changes that were in process into the new repo and resolving gaps.

One thing I noticed about the migration was that the typings folder was not migrated.  I remember that the typings implementation seemed to be going through some evolution about a year ago.

So what pattern should I follow to ensure that my typings are configured appropriately for my app using the latest standards? Are typings installed by default when running "npm install" against the package.json configuration? It looks like ts files may get installed into related subdirs in node_modules.  So can I delete the typings folder in the root level of my app as an obsolete carryover?

Comment: Use @Types and install what you need https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/@types.html

Answer (score 0):

I share with the practices in my current company. You may find your answer depending on your build and deploy process.

- We are using TFS Server and we have migrated our repo from TFS to git.
- In our codebase, either under TFS or under git, we *don't commit* npm packages (including @types), typings (in an old project), compiled CSS (from LESS/SCSS) / JS (from TS), currently with the appropriate `.gitignore` file.
- A build process is configured on the TFS server to restore npm packages, typings, to compile CSS/JS, ...
- If you are using Angular CLI, the build process should include a step to launch `ng build --prod`.
- The build artifact is then used to deploy the web sites.